# SCNScene issue in Swift: nothing shows in SCNView

Tags: cocoa, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to do [this](http://ronnqvi.st/3d-with-scenekit/) in Swift. However my SCNView doesn't show anything. I checked the connections in IB and everything is fine. I assume that I made an error while translating the source code from *Objective C* to *Swift*. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var sceneview: SCNView

@IBOutlet var status: NSTextField
var statusCounter: Int = 1


@IBAction func paintRectButton (sender: AnyObject) {
    status.stringValue = "Paint (#\(statusCounter++))"

    var scene: SCNScene = SCNScene()

    var cameraNode: SCNNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 15, 30)
    cameraNode.transform = CATransform3DRotate(cameraNode.transform, 7.0, 1, 0, 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

    var spotlight: SCNLight = SCNLight()
    spotlight.type = SCNLightTypeSpot
    spotlight.color = NSColor.redColor()

    var spotlightNode: SCNNode = SCNNode()
    spotlightNode.light = spotlight
    spotlightNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-2, 1, 0)

    cameraNode.addChildNode(spotlightNode)

    let boxSide = 15.0
    var box: SCNBox =
        SCNBox(width: boxSide, height: boxSide, length: boxSide, chamferRadius: 0)

    var boxNode: SCNNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
    boxNode.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(3, 0, 1, 0)

    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)

    sceneview.scene = scene
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why nothing shows up is that the camera is looking in a direction where there isn't any geometry object to be rendered. The Objective-C code uses `-M_PI/7.0` (≈ -0.4488 radians) for the rotation angle of the camera and but your Swift code is using `7.0` (≈ 0.7168 radians (the remainder after dividing by π)). Change the Swift code to:

```
cameraNode.transform = CATransform3DRotate(cameraNode.transform, -M_PI/7.0, 1, 0, 0)
```

---

A similar mistake seem to have happened with the rotation of the box where the original code uses the angle `M_PI_2/3` and the Swift code is using the angle `3`.

```
boxNode.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2/3.0, 0, 1, 0)
```